# How to get value in JSF xhtml page from f:selectItems

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, xhtml

I have select menu in JSF xhtml page. The select menu contains a

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.statusFlag}">

    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.statusList}"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

The value is be being stored in status.

This works fine. I have to print the value in h:outputText in next column.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.statusFlag}" />
```

prints code rather value corresponding value of code, since the value is in statusList.

Is there any way to achieve this without having to modify the backing bean.

Comment: What are you trying to print out ? A property of statusFlag ? And what do you mean by _since the value is in statusList_ ? Your problem is not well explained, personally I don't understand.

Comment: With PrimeFaces you can use `p:ajax event="change"` and re-render `h:outputText`. Similar with RichFaces: `<a4j:ajax event="change" render="outputTextId" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps implement some sort of `<f:ajax>` within your `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

You could also use jquery with an `onchange()` event.

```
$('#select').change(function() {
    $('#outText').val($('#select').val());
});
```

Hope that helps!